# Can we use Select query output as Column alias 

Tags: t-sql

i need a select statements output as a columns's alias

is it possible

examples

```
select columnname as (select value from tablename)  from tablename
```

output

values

1

2

3

Comment: OP says, "is it possible". Did you try to run this in SSMS? or is the real question how?

Comment: i just want to know whether it is possible or not.am running that in SSMS and got error

Answer (score 1):

no you can't, see this:

```
declare @a table (rowvalue varchar(20))
insert @a values ('aaa')
insert @a values ('bbb')
insert @a values ('ccc')
insert @a values ('ddd')

declare @x table (id int,rowvalue varchar(20))
insert @x values (1, 'wowwee')
insert @x values (2, 'noooo!')

select a.rowvalue as  (select rowvalue from @x where id=1)
    from @a a
```

OUTPUT:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near '('.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.
```

you'll have to use dynamic sql for this.

**EDIT** to show dynamic sql:

```
declare @SQL varchar(500)
       ,@ColumnName varchar(20)
create table #a  (rowvalue varchar(20))
insert #a values ('aaa')
insert #a values ('bbb')
insert #a values ('ccc')
insert #a values ('ddd')

declare @x table (id int,rowvalue varchar(20))
insert @x values (1, 'wowwee')
insert @x values (2, 'noooo!')

SELECT @ColumnName=rowvalue FROM @x where id=1

set @SQL='select a.rowvalue as '+@ColumnName+' from #a a'
exec(@SQL)
```

OUTPUT:

```
wowwee
--------------------
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd

(4 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: dynamic sql like??give me some examples

Comment: edited answer to show dynamic sql.  Notice I had to change the local variable table @a to a temp table #a because local variables are out of scope within the EXEC() command.  This shouldn't be an issue if you are using regualr permanent tables, I was just using local variable tables so anyone could run the sample code without adding tables to their system.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Select (Select value from Tablename) as Columnname from Tablename

The output should resemble the following

ColumnName
- 1
- 2
- 3

Comment: the values are supposed to be listed in a column

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to quit de AS word in tsql, I mean:

```
select column name (select value from tablename) from tablename
```

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake, is as Eon said before. I tried it out a couple of minutes ago...